# Fragment transitions not working in jetpack Navigation framework

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-jetpack

Transitions not working even after setting the enter, exit, popEnter and popExit transitions.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/introFragment"
    android:name="IntroFragment"
    android:label="IntroFragment" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_introFragment_to_signinFragment"
        app:destination="@id/signinFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_from_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_to_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_from_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_to_right"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/nav_graph" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_introFragment_to_signupFragment"
        app:destination="@id/signupFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_from_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_to_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_from_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_to_right"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/nav_graph" />
</fragment>
```

I am using

```
def nav_version = "1.0.0-alpha05"
// Navigation Component - Jetpack
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
androidTestImplementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-testing-ktx:$nav_version"
```

My navigate code is

```
button.setOnClickListener(
            Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.signinFragment))
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does animation is flickering or not working at all?

Comment: No animation at all.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The issue is with my navigation code. I have to change my destination id to action id for my transitions to work!

```
button.setOnClickListener(Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(
                                  R.id.action_introFragment_to_signinFragment))
```

May be this is due to multiple actions on my destination.